# what is the easiest way to implement particle system without openGL nor cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, particles

All is in the question, I've worked enough with cocos2d to say it's a great library but today I only wanna use particle system in a total UIKit project. As long as I know, unfortunately, I have to implement one with OpenGL.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Core Animation and [CAReplicatorLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAReplicatorLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) to generate particle systems without having to drop down to OpenGL ES.  Joe Ricioppo's "[To 1e100f And Beyond with CAReplicatorLayer](http://tumbljack.com/post/223478784/to-1e100f-and-beyond-with-careplicatorlayer)" gives an introduction to how to use this class.  Also, Apple has their [ReplicatorDemo](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/ReplicatorDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application, which I [ported to the iPad](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ReplicatorDemoiPad.zip).

On the Mac, there's also the [CAEmitterLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAEmitterLayer), which became available in iOS as of 5.0.  Apple's sample applications for this include [Fire](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Fire/Introduction/Intro.html), which shows off fire and smoke effects, and [Fireworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Fireworks/Introduction/Intro.html), which simulates a fireworks display.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you said, unfortunately, CAEmitterLayer doesn't exist... Let's create a particle system emitter myself with CAReplicatorLayer =/ Cya

Comment: I want to update this post to guide new users. CAEmitterLayer now available in iOS.

Comment: @fyasar - Good point. I've updated my answer to indicate that this is available in iOS 5.0+.

Answer (score 4):

For a UIKit-only project you could use [Particle Playground](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/mac-apps/particle-playground/) ([Mac App Store Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/particle-playground/id600661093)) to configure your emitter on your mac in a simulator and the export it as code ready for integration in your project. PP is quite similar to Particle Designer as mentioned by matt.

If you don't want to use a helper so you can dive deeper into the CAEmitter(Layer/Cell) then I would recommend reading [this tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial) or [this article on Arg! Team's blog](http://blog.argteam.com/tag/caemitterlayer/). They have helped me a lot in configuring my own emitters.

Full disclosure: I am the developer of Particle Playground. I grew tired of the whole tweak-recompile-observe-loop and developed PP in my spare time.

Answer (score 3):

Note that CAEmitterLayer was added in iOS 5. That makes particle effects much easier.

I haven't used it yet, but I have seen examples that do. I'm not sure how hard Apple's fire sample would be to port to iOS 5. I might just give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I too, find designing particles in UIKit a challenge so I created an app for it. Used it to create various particles in my games now. So easy! It is a iDevice app so  you can play with particles while in a bus or at a mall and immediately export out the codes.

If anybody is interested:
http://iapps.emirbytes.com/particlex/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In UIKit you build particle systems by using the QuartzCore framework. For a complete example read this post:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CAEmitterLayer`

Here are some tutorials

- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/37/5/creating-a-particle-system-using-caemitterlayer
- https://medium.com/call-voicy/comets-animating-particles-in-swift-3431a7f1b250

Here are some ways to playground it

- Here is how to playground using SpriteKit http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Sprite_Kit_Particle_Emitter_Tutorial
- Xcode 8+ also includes Playground, you can create a Playground to play around with it https://github.com/onmyway133/ParticlePlayground

Answer (score -1):

You should also consider Particle Emitter (http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) which was designed to be used as a cocos2d plug-in.

A tutorial is provided here:
http://www.71squared.com/2009/05/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-8-particle-emitter/

Comment: The question was about an UIKit project, not Cocos2D. Plz read the question before answer anything.